# C++ How can achieve this Interface configuration?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I certainly don't know how to title this question, sorry.

I'm having some problems to design the following system.

I need a class which will make some work, but this work can be done in a bunch of different ways, say that this work will be made through "drivers".

These drivers can have different interfaces and because of that I need to build a wrapper for each driver.

So I got (or I need) this:

```
       Me --->    MainClass   ---->    Wrapper ---->  Drivers
```

MainClass is the class I will touch and will call the drivers methods through different wrappers.

Here an example of usage:

```
MainClass worker;
worker.set_driver("driver_0");
worker.start_process();      //Start process calls a wrapper method which calls a driver's method.
```

To achieve this I made an interface class:

```
class Driver_Interface : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
   Driver_Interface(QObject* parent=0) : QObject(parent){}
   virtual bool open()=0;
   virtual bool close()=0;
   virtual bool write()=0;
   virtual bool set_config()=0;
};
```

A driver wrapper has this shape:

```
class Driver0 : public Driver_Interface
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Driver0( QObject* parent=0);
    Driver0();

    bool open();
    bool close();
    bool write();
    bool set_config();
};
```

Finally here comes the conflicting point, defining the MainClass:
I would like to avoid to create one member for each wrapper, so I tried this, and right now compiler doesn't complains:

```
class MainClass
{
public:
    MainClass();
    ~MainClass();
    void init();
    void set_driver( const QString& );
    void start_process();
protected:
    QString driver_str;
    Driver_Interface* driver;  //!<--- Here Here!!!
};
```

When setting the driver chosen, I do this:

```
if( driver_str.compare("driver_0")==0 )
     this->driver = new Driver_0();
```

1. Is this a valid C++ configuration or will I have problems sooner or later? 
   Basically, what worries me is the creation of the driver of a different type from Driver_Interface, I'm seeing that it casts automatically and no one complains...
2. Actually I have some problems now compiling, the infamous vtables not defined in Driver_0... does this have some relation with what I want to achieve? **UPDATED**: I fixed this by deleting the *Driver_Interface* constructor.

Comment: Why are you using a string to specify the driver? Are you reading user input for the driver selection?

Comment: Just for lazyness, I know I should use an ENUM for example, but I'm just starting with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me your basic idea seems to be fine. I would consider separating the creation of drivers into a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) (or at least a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)) though.

Comment: the new Driver_0() is made inside "MainClass", so it is encapsulated. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @clinisbut, as the first step, yes. Depending on the situation, I might prefer migrating the creation code out of `MainClass`, to eliminate dependencies to concrete Driver subclasses. It may not be a problem if you only have a few fixed subclasses, and creating them is simple. But if you have many, and/or creating them is complicated, the creation code clutters `MainClass`. Or if you expect to add new ones, without this separation you would need to recompile MainClass every time a driver is added or removed.

Answer (score 1):

This seems reasonable to me.  Having a [FactoryMethod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or class ([AbstractFactory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)) that creates an object of the required concrete subclass based on some config value is a common pattern.

You could consider having the `MainClass` implement something like

```
DriverInterface* createDriver(const string& driverType)
```

instead of encapsulating the resulting concrete `DriverInterface` subclass in `MainClass`.  But if you only ever want one concrete `DriverInterface` instance, the above looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass "driver_0" to the constructor, and call MainClass::set_driver from there. You can then make MainClass::set_driver private unless you need to change drivers.